# How do I remove SVN revision?

Tags: svn, revision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove an accidentally put large file (4GB) from Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648115/how-to-remove-an-accidentally-put-large-file-4gb-from-subversion-repository)

I'm using a SVN hosting provider. I checked in some large binaries in and went over my 2GB quota. I don't need to have those under source control obviously so I removed them.

The size of the repository stayed over the limit though. The guys at the hosting company say it's because the large binaries are still in that revision.

The guys at the hosting provider are pretty cool about it, but if possible I would like to remove that revision. I've made a number of commits between the add and delete and since.

I'm on a branch off the main trunk (I think that's the correct term?).

I don't think I can just go in the history and delete the revision. The only other thing I can think off is to:

a. Merge the branch I'm in back to the trunk and then delete the branch.
b. Delete the repository, create a new one, then re-import everything back in.

I'm not sure either of those will work. What would you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite history in Subversion by only one way

- Create dump(s) of repository (`svnadmin dump` or *some way* in Web UI of provider), which skip(s) bad revision
- Delete old repository (optional)
- Create new repository, load dump with correct data

Comment: Ok great. I looked over the documentation and it seems I can use svnadmin dump svndumpfilter and svnadmin load to achieve this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2036161 - svndumpfilter does not remove revisions from dump, only subtree. You have to have set of dumps with -r option

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user2036161 - ok, without commands and logs at start. In order to exclude some file totally from **any** mentions in SVN-repo you **must delete revisions** from repository, which affect (any way) this file. I.e you must have in dumps **intermittent history**. Dump can include only range of history, but can't have excluded revisions in the middle of body, thus - every exluded revisions means: "new dump *from next of excluded* to *before previous to next excluded*"